# Sending localized messages to Django users

Tags: django, localization

I'm having trouble with sending localized messages to Django users using the

```
user.message_set.create(message="Message")
```

mechanism. First of all,

```
user.message_set.create(message=_("Message"))
```

flat out doesn't work, SQLite says it won't accept the non-ascii parameter (localized message contains special characters).

```
user.message_set.create(message=unicode(_("Message")))
```

sends the original English message regardless of the preferred language (other translated parts of the app do work correctly).

Using a hardcoded localized message like this

```
user.message_set.create(message=u"Localized message áýčš")
```

is the only thing that works but that implies that I'd be able to only use one language.

**How can I send users localized messages loaded from LC_MESSAGES?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried localizing the message right before you display it?

In your view:

```
user.message_set.create(message="Message")
```

In your template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li>{% trans message %}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

This way, you don't have to store any odd characters in your database.

Comment: theres's one problem with this. I'm guessing that 'makemessages' command won't catch the string and you'll have to remember to edit django.po file manually, or use a workaround - add a dummy line with _("Message") in the .py code

Comment: there's `django.utils.translation.gettext_noop` for that. Also, `{% trans message %}` won't work (at least on 1.3/new contrib.messages). Use `{% trans message.message %}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
user.message_set.create(message=_("Message"))
```

... should work. Are you using the latest version of SQLite, does UTF-8 support have to be enabled somehow? Are you storing non-ascii characters in SQLite elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not using the latest SQLite since the CentOS setup I have wouldn't support it. But I definitely do store non-ascii characters elsewhere in the database.

Comment: That's what's suprising to me - most stuff works, it's just the message system that doesn't.

Comment: Could it be that in the context you're in, _ is not aliased properly to ugettext? 

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#s-standard-translation

Comment: Nope, _ is aliased and works correctly a few lines below for other stuff.